# Ubuntu 20.04 reboots to black screen after installing Radeon AMD Pro drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

After I install the driver my PC boots to a black screen with a blinking cursor. I can Ctrl alt F2 into tty to uninstall the drivers. Once this is done the PC works fine, however, I need the drivers. Anyone is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I too have tried to Amd pro drivers. Got same issue. I went to safe mode to uninstall that one to boot into ubuntu. Got a feeling that it's hopeless, but after digging into a lot I found this:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:c0000000-c0ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:c1400000-c143ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c1440000-c145ffff
```

That means the required driver was already embedded in my system. When I tried to install AMD Pro it was sort of conflicting. The package installs, and uses DKMS to compile a new initrd image file.  Then, when I reboot the system, that new image causes a kernel panic.(Found after googling, Can't describe in depth).

You can alternatively try this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
```

In case you need to revert back to your original Ubuntu AMD Radeon drivers you can remove the PPA driver installation using the below commands:

```
$ sudo apt install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```